# xslt fo:marker sometimes doesn't display the right content

Tags: xslt, apache-fop

I'm using xslt 1.0

I have a header which should be updated with some info from one of the recursive methods which creates a table inside a page sequence (for ex. node id).
sometimes the info from the table should be divided between two pages (the content should flow to a table in the next page).
when the flow occurs the marker displays the wrong info.
here is how I defined the marker:

```
<fo:retrieve-marker retrieve-class-name="stepID" retrieve-boundary="page-sequence"/>
```

here is how i set the marker:

```
<fo:marker retrieve-boundary="page" marker-class-name="stepID" retrieve-position="first-starting-within-page"><xsl:value-of select="$curStepCatId"/></fo:marker>
```

I'm not sure what's causing that error, i have tried different retrieve-boundary, and different retrieve-position, but all failed.
If i use a message to display the value before setting it with the retrieve i do get the right value.

when referring to wrong value, i mean it displays the next node's id and not the current.

btw, I'm not setting page breaks in the xslt at all.

here is how the flow goes:

- page sequence

  - call template

    - call template - recursive

      - call template - optional (sometimes it does and sometimes it doesn't)
      - call template - recursive

        - call template - recursive

          - call template
          - call template - recursive
          - call template - recursive
          - block which contains the marker
          - block which which contains table which calls template recursively.
          - block which which contains table which calls template recursively.

my problem lays in the pages which contain the tables...if the table is in 1 page, than everything is alright, but if it flows to another page, the marker shows incorrect values.
i tried to move the block which contains the marker to be the last block...didn't help

Comment: Please share your code, which you missed.

Comment: Low quality question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: @NavinRawat code shared.

Comment: @markdark not sure why its low quality, the documentation regarding the use of marker is not that good...I'm sure that others will benefit from understanding how to use it properly.

Comment: before your edit it was low quality

Comment: The marker is set inside what? Showing the code for the marker is worthless, showing in what structure the marker is set and it's progression dimension is all that counts.

Comment: @KevinBrown the marker is simply inside a plain block, I will post tomorrow the full flow, but its a page seq which calls a recursive template the last lines in the template are the marker lines, which are wrapped in a block.

Comment: @KevinBrown I've updated the question so the full flow will be understood.